# Does Sysout affects tomcat performance?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, log4j

We have a java web application which runs on tomcat, In that application lot of System.out.println statements are used. Will this affect the application performance

**Note: tomcat is running as service and all the sysout are in the tomcat stdout logs.**

Answer (score 1):

Excessive logging does inhibit performance. In the worst case scenario, where your logging service is poorly configured, logs can potentially fill your hard drive which may lead to all kinds problems.